# How to display time with different field in calendar?

Tags: 7, datetime

How to display time on calendar if time is different field created usin [CCK Time](https://drupal.org/project/cck_time) Module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by adding field group in calendar style display.

Added time field in views and edit the settings of calendar style plugin. There is a option to group field by hour. I selected my field.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you use the module Calendar you can edit the Calendar View and then switch the date field in all it's instances (at least look under contextual filters also).

Another way to do it could be to change the widget for the ordinary date field so that it uses CCK Time input widget, that way you don't have to change the Calendar view.